# Show that $\gcd(ca,cb) = |c|\gcd(a,b)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, gcd-and-lcm

I understand this:

If $\gcd(a,b)=d$ and $\gcd(ac,bc)=e$, then $d|a \Rightarrow dc|ac$ and $d|b \Rightarrow dc|bc$, so this is equivalent to multiplying $c$ by $\gcd(a,b)$.

What I don't understand so well is why the $|c|$ (absolute value). Why can't $c$ be negative?

Comment: What is $\gcd(-20,-30)$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown It's 10

Comment: That's $10$ times $\gcd(2,3)$ then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, gcd of two integers is the largest **positive integer** that divides each of the integers. (See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor))